# SQL Sum of Count Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query and I'd like to get a sum of the count values in the 'membership count' column. How can I get the sum of the count values?

```
select count(MAJOR_KEY) 'membership count', chapter
from Name
where MEMBER_RECORD = 1 and
(STATUS = 'I' or STATUS = 'SN')
group by CHAPTER
order by CHAPTER
```

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a last row with the sum then use [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-rollup):

```
select count(MAJOR_KEY) [membership count], chapter
from Name
where MEMBER_RECORD = 1 and (STATUS = 'I' or STATUS = 'SN')
group by ROLLUP(CHAPTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a total count from all the chapters you can use rollup/cube

try: group by **rollup**(CHAPTER)

```
select sum(c) as [membership count], chapter
from 
(
   select count(MAJOR_KEY) c, chapter
   from Name
   where MEMBER_RECORD = 1 and
   (STATUS = 'I' or STATUS = 'SN')
   group by rollup(CHAPTER)
) sub
group by CHAPTER
order by CHAPTER
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by`:

```
select count(MAJOR_KEY) as membershipcount
from Name
where MEMBER_RECORD = 1 and
      STATUS in ('I', 'SN');
```

Note that I also simplified the `WHERE` clause by using `IN`.